# This script won't work in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get the below code to work in WordPress, but I cannot get it to work. The form displays properly, but selecting the different options does nothing. I cannot figure out how to get jQuery to work. [The code itself does work.](http://jsfiddle.net/2yEcm/) Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<style type="text/css">
.hide {
     display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j("#choices").change(function(){
   $j('.hide').slideUp();
   $j('#'+this.value).slideDown()
});
</script>
<form>
<select id="choices">
        <option value="none">Select an option...</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
        <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="option1" class="hide">Option 1 TEXT</div>
<div id="option2" class="hide">Option 2 TEXT</div>
<div id="option3" class="hide">Option 3 TEXT</div>
<div id="option4" class="hide">Option 4 TEXT</div>
<div id="option5" class="hide">Option 5 TEXT</div>
<div id="option6" class="hide">Option 6 TEXT</div>
<div id="option7" class="hide">Option 7 TEXT</div>
```

Comment: Your form end tag does not have a matching opening tag. Same in your fiddle too.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. The actual page on my site does have one; it must've vanished when I copy-pasted.

Comment: Have you tried inserting the absolute path of jQuery file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two popular caveats.

- DOM is not ready when your scripts are executed

  ```
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(document).ready(function(){
   $j("#choices").change(function(){
      $j('.hide').slideUp();
      $j('#'+this.value).slideDown()
   });
  })
  ```
- your IDs might be used twice. Change IDs to classes in HTML and JS. Check with

  ```
  console.log( $j("#choices") )
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Also, [the safe and recommended method of adding JavaScript to a WordPress generated page is by using wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: I tried to figure that out and I couldn't, which is why I ended up embedding it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("#choices").change(function(){
           $j('.hide').slideUp();
           $j('#'+this.value).slideDown()
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will make sure the jQuery code doesn't execute until the DOM is ready.

Comment: Your point seems to be correct, but the script didn't work. Fenchurch's above comment did work, however. Thank you!